# rename bag in pig when used with TOBAG function

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to rename a Pig bag containing 3 tuples `($2,$7)`, `($8,$9)`, and `($3,$6)`.

**Example**:

```
collected = FOREACH collect GENERATE $0 as guest_id
          , TOTUPLE($4, $5) AS guest_group
          , TOBAG(TOTUPLE($2, $7) AS demographic_type
                , TOTUPLE($8, $9) AS demographic_level
                , TOTUPLE($3, $6) AS demographic
                , $1 AS quater_end_date) AS guest_demographic;
```

But it's not working.  However, if I execute the below command which renames the tuples, it works fine.

```
collected = FOREACH collect GENERATE $0 as guest_id
          , TOTUPLE($4, $5) AS guest_group
          , TOTUPLE($2, $7) AS demographic_type
          , TOTUPLE($8, $9) AS demographic_level
          , TOTUPLE($3, $6) AS demographic
          , $1 as quater_end_date;

DESCRIBE collected;
```

> collected: {guest_id: int,guest_group: (gst_ten_pcnt_flag: chararray,gst_two_pcnt_flag: chararray),demographic_type: (typ_code: int,typ_name: chararray),demographic_level: (dmg_typ_lvl: chararray,dmg_typ_lvl_name: chararray),demographic: (dmg_val: chararray,val_name: chararray),quater_end_date: chararray}

Can someone suggest how to rename a bag in Pig so that when I describe it I get

> collected: {guest_id: int,guest_group: (gst_ten_pcnt_flag: chararray,gst_two_pcnt_flag: chararray), demographic: {demographic_type: (typ_code: int,typ_name: chararray),demographic_level: (dmg_typ_lvl: chararray,dmg_typ_lvl_name: chararray),demographic: (dmg_val: chararray,val_name: chararray),quater_end_date: chararray}}

Answer (score 0):

Refer : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#tobag

Usage : TOBAG(field1, field2, ...)

```
collected = FOREACH collect Generate $0 as guest_id, TOTUPLE($4, $5) as guest_group, TOBAG($2, $7) as demographic_type, TOTUPLE($8, $9) as demographic_level, TOTUPLE($3, $6) as demographic, $1 as quater_end_date ...;
```